# printing invalid options using arrays

Tags: arrays, bash

I am storing details on invalid option to a function using arrays, `w` to store the positional index and `warg` to store the option name.

```
 declare -a w=()
 declare -a warg=()

 local k=0 vb=0 ctp="" sty=""
 while (( $# > 0 )); do
  k=$((k+1))
  arg="$1"
  case $arg in
   ("--vlt")
     ctp="$vlt" ; r=$k ; shift 1 ;;
   ("--blu")
     blu=$(tput setaf 12)
     ctp="$blu" ; r=$k ; shift 1 ;;
   ("--grn")
     grn=$(tput setaf 2)
     ctp="$grn" ; r=$k ; shift 1 ;;
   ("-m"*)
     sty="${1#-m}" ; r=$k ; shift 1 ;;
   ("--")
     shift 1 ; break ;;
   ("-"*)
     w+=($k) ; warg+=("$arg")
     shift 1 ;;
   (*)
     break ;;
  esac
 done
```

After that, I try to loop through the invalid options but as one can see, the positional elements in `iw` do not map to `${warg[$iw]}`, in a way that I can print the invalid option name.  What can I do?

```
 r=4
 local iw
 for iw in "${w[@]}"; do
  if (( iw < r )); then
    printf '%s\n' "Invalid option | ${warg[$iw]}"
  fi
 done
```

Answer (score 0):

Numerically-indexed arrays don't have to have sequentical indices.

Using an array of color name to number reduces the duplication in the case branches.

```sh
declare -A colors=(
  [blu]=12
  [grn]=2
  [ylw]=3
  [orn]=166
  [pur]=93
  [red]=1
  [wht]=7
)
  
declare -a warg=()

for ((i = 1; i <= $#; i++)); do
    arg=${!i}   # value at position $i
    case $arg in
        --blu|--grn|--ylw|--orn|--pur|--red|--wht)
            ctp=$(tput setaf "${colors[${arg#--}]}") ;;
        --vlt) ctp="$vlt" ;;
        -m*) sty="${arg#-m}" ;;
        --)  break ;;
        -*)  warg[i]=$arg ;;
        *)   break ;;
    esac
done

numArgs=$i
shift $numArgs

# iterate over the _indices_ of the wrong args array
for i in "${!warg[@]}"; do
  echo "wrong arg ${warg[i]} at postition $i"
done
```

That is untested, so there may be bugs

Comment: should the echo use `${warg[$i]}` instead of `${warg[i]}`.

Comment: In an arithmetic expression, bash lets you drop the `$` from variables. That's what's happening in the arithmetic `for`. The index part of a numerically indexed array expansion is an arithmetic expression. So, it's OK to use `${warg[i]}`

Answer (score 0):

Addressing just the mapping issue between `w[]` and `warg[]` ...

The problem seems to be that `$k` is being incremented for *every* `$arg`, but the index for `warg[]` is only  incremented for an 'invalid' `$arg`.

If the sole purpose of the `w[]` array is to track the position of 'invalid' args then you can eliminate the `w[]` array and populate `warg[]` as a sparse array with the following change to the current code:

```
# replace:

warg+=("$arg")

# with:

warg[$k]="$arg"
```

With this change your `for` loop becomes:

```
for iw in "${!warg[@]}"
do
    ....
    printf '%s\n' "Invalid option | ${warg[$iw]}"
done
```

Comment: Do I have to call `declare -A warg` to be able to utilise `warg[$k]="$arg"`?

Comment: `declare -A` is for associative arrays; `declare -a` is for normal, or integer-indexed, arrays; since `$k` is an integer you should be find with `declare -a`